# Cómo identificar CD y CI en caso de verbos transitivos

Tags: laísmo-leísmo-loísmo, complemento-directo

El ejemplo que estoy tratando de comprender con el objetivo de evitar leísmos es este:

Alguien agarró a Carlos del tobillo.

¿Es CD Carlos, o el tobillo? Ambos están siendo agarrados al mismo tiempo. Si lo pienso me resulta más directo el agarre a la parte del cuerpo, y como consecuencia más indirecta, a Carlos.

Si transformamos la frase a pasiva quedaría:

"Carlos fue agarrado del tobillo por alguien" o

"Carlos fue agarrado por alguien del tobillo"

¿Se agarra el tobillo (CD) de Carlos (CI)?
o
¿Se agarra a Carlos (qué se agarra, a Carlos, CD) del tobillo (de dónde)? En este último caso qué función tendría "del tobillo" en la frase?

Dependiendo de esto se usará "lo" o "le" para sustituir a Carlos:

Lo agarró del tobillo.

Le agarró del tobillo.

A mí me suena mejor la segunda, pero pensaba que Carlos era CD y, por lo tanto, debía ser sustituido por "lo".
¿Es "le" incorrecto en este caso?
¿Modifica la parte del cuerpo el significado de la frase y su estructura?
¿Estoy confundiendo CD con CI?

Comment: Recomendación: no uses criterios semánticos para decidir sobre categorías sintácticas. Transformar la oración en pasiva y probar la sustitución de los objetos por "le" y "lo" son estrategias correctas. Tratar de razonar cosas como "¿quién es más afectado, Carlos o el tobillo?" puede dar resultados incorrectos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En la oración:

- Alguien agarró a Carlos del tobillo.

"a Carlos" es objeto directo porque puede convertirse en el sujeto de la voz pasiva (Carlos fue agarrado del tobillo) o reemplazarse por el pronombre *lo/la/los/las* (en este caso, "lo": Lo agarraron del tobillo) y "del tobillo" es un circunstancial de modo o lugar, pues indica el modo o lugar de donde lo agarraron. Un objeto directo o indirecto nunca puede empezar con la preposición "de".

Si, en cambio, tenemos la oración:

- Le agarraron el tobillo a Carlos.

"el tobillo" es objeto directo y "a Carlos" es objeto indirecto duplicado por "le". Si pronominalizamos el objeto directo, "le" cambia por "se" y obtenemos:

- Se lo agarraron.

En síntesis, si el complemento puede reemplazarse por "lo", "la", "los" o "las", es DIRECTO (OD). Si el complemento puede reemplazarse por "le" o "les", es INDIRECTO (OI). Cuando los dos complementos están pronominalizados, "le" y "les" se transforman en "se". Así, en "se lo agarraron" *se* se refiere a "Carlos" y es OI mientras que *lo* se refiere a "tobillo" y es OD.

Coincido con el comentario de Pablo en cuanto a que puede ser confuso mezclar categorías semánticas y sintácticas, pero al mismo tiempo en la oración:

- Agarraron a Carlos del tobillo.

"Carlos" es quien fue agarrado (OD), mientras que en:

- (Le) Agarraron el tobillo a Carlos.

"el tobillo" es lo que fue agarrado (OD), y Carlos fue indirectamente afectado (OI) porque fue su tobillo el que fue agarrado.

"Le agarraron del tobillo" es un caso de leísmo. Lo correcto sería:

- Lo agarraron del tobillo.

o

- Le agarraron el tobillo.

Comment: Gracias, se entiende mucho mejor cuando alguien lo explica correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando la persona es CD (`a él` y `a ella`) y `tobillo` CI:

- **SI** →  (Alguien) Lo agarró (a él) del tobillo
- **SI** →  (Alguien) La agarró (a ella) del tobillo
- **NO** →  (Alguien) Le agarró (a él o ella) del tobillo

Cuando el `tobillo` es CD y la persona CI

- **NO** →  (Alguien) Lo agarró el tobillo (a él)
- **NO** →  (Alguien) La agarró el tobillo (a ella)
- **SI** →  (Alguien) Le agarró el tobillo (a él o ella)

Ejemplos:

- La miró a los ojos y le cogió la mano

(alguien) La (a ella – CD) miró a los ojos (CI) y le (a ella – CI) cogió la mano (CD)